# Python 3: Please help.. Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3292, 3326]

Tags: linear-regression, model-selection

I am trying the below code:

```
X = np.array(df.drop(['label'], 1))
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
X = X[:-forecast_out]
df.dropna(inplace=True)
y = np.array(df['label'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
X = X.reshape(X.shape[1:])
X = X.tranpose()
```

and getting error:

> Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3292, 3326]

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: It seems you drop the NA's from `df` after having extracted `X` and before extracting `y`, therefore `X` and `y` have different number of elements

Comment: I am trying to reshape the X so I am not sure how to do it since it's not a single feature. how do i chose the value. eg: X.reshape(1,  -1) is for single feature. So what should i write in my code? X.reshape(what value should i write)